# Increasing quality of [multiple/competing] answers as the question approaches/reaches highly viewed volume

Tags: discussion

In this question [here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431628/how-to-combine-2-or-more-querysets-in-a-django-view/42186970#42186970), the answer is viewed a large number of times (currently 200K+). The answers are somewhat varied, although this is because I am becoming better at Python and Django. The answers' users who have a better reputation (and thusly a better understanding of the SO ecosystem) sometimes offer better reasoning/justification/appeal to why their answer is better, regardless of their answer's position with regards to reputation accrual. Can we offer a way (either through the author's own tagging or through a community) to identify the reasons why one answer has advantages (in general or over another)?

The UI would be somehow in the answer section (below as a whole separate part or to the right (albeit there is minimum space there currently) that would allow them to tag or describe their dis/advantages, such as

- language/framework versions compatibility
- language/architectural requirements
- computation cost/expense

I know that a great question takes a long time to ask, and I know that a great answer takes even longer (evidenced especially by the time and edit count of community answers). In the interim,

**Is there a way to encourage answer authors to increase quality by addressing additional attributes of a question (often assumptions made my early and learning programmers) without increasing the minimum requirement to answer a question?**

Comment: How would this be different from the existing voting mechanism? You want to, essentially, offer a *reason* for a vote?

Comment: I was not thinking of changing the voting mechanism.   I was thinking some type of UI indicator (flag, box, tag) that would be visible on the answer (or the question) to encourage users to highlight their approach and assumptions.  Whether it is categorized as I mentioned or left open and reevaluated later could be discussed.  As far as a reason for a vote, maybe it could be considered as that, but I was shooting for clarification.   As a question gains views, there can be assumptions about its underlying reasoning.   As it also gains answers, there is a clear difference in what is going on.

Comment: With high views and high answers, that means the question is not fully specific, and answers are providing different reasonings/assumptions/solutions.    Not everyone includes those reasonings, and even sometimes they are added later once the answer or question gains popularity.    (this can be seen in the timing of the edits as the question popularity grows over time).

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you are actually proposing. I also don't follow the logic that a large number of views/answers implies "the question is not fully specific". What part of the site's UI/UX do you actually want to change? We already encourage answerers to address all relevant aspects of a question. What more encouragement should we offer, aside from upvotes?

Comment: We have comments for clarification, and you can certainly comment asking the poster to address whatever shortcomings you see in an answer...